# Xbmcbuntu install won't proceed

Tags: system-installation

This question is about xbmcbuntu, hope that's ok. I'm trying to install it on my computer now for a while (hope to make it a HTPC/server) but I just can't get it to work. Here's my hardware configuration:

Motherboard MSI FM2-A75MA-E35
CPU: AMD A6 5600K
8 GB of memory
Onboard video
Crucial 64 GB SSD (formatted in FAT)
WD RED 3 TB Harddrive (want to run windows home server in virtualbox)
350 Watt PSU

Now I've been trying to install it using USB using Linuxlive USB creator, Unetbootin, Universial USB installer, YUMI and regular dvd with ISO but all don't work. (I set the bootorder configuration right) My motherboard boots properly, displaying the usual stuff and after that I get to the installmenu of xmbcbuntu. Here I can choose whatever I want but all I get after selecting an option is a white screen. I tried to adjust the installation using TAB with removing quiet splash and adding `nomodeset` (I guess in case my onboard video driver doesn't get supported). All i get is a long list with all kids of information ending with `ACPI: core revision 20120320`. Also tried all of the options above with the regular version of Ubuntu (12.04) but face the same problem.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong and how to proceed?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried disconnecting the Hard drive and just installing to the SSD? (occam's razor).

Comment: Thanks, but yes I have. Didn't make any difference unfortunately

Comment: What's the BIOS version? You may need to update it to support that CPU. You can find the supported list here http://us.msi.com/product/mb/FM2A75MAE35.html#/?div=CPUSupport with a link to the required BIOS. Be sure to follow BIOS update instructions carefully to avoid any unforeseen circumstances.

Comment: Version was 1.3. After updating the BIOS to 2.3 the installation indeed proceeded! Thanks for the suggestion!! Everyting is working fine now

Answer (score 0):

Update your BIOS to the latest version. Follow the manufacturers recommendations for doing so. This will typically resolve problems.